# Wipers come on in the off position

Tags: chevrolet, windshield-wipers, corvette

1998 Corvette wipers comes on while in the off position. I changed the motor and the switch. Is there a relay some where? What should I do next?

Comment: Are they on *all the time* in the off position? Or is it intermittent?

Comment: No they come on  for     a second when i start the car an  while im driving,and they stop in the up right position,then they tart back for a few wipes an stop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably your Wiper Motor Pulse Board Module (ACDELCO pn 12367295). This will control the behavior of your wipers. If any of the board has corrosion or a bad part on it, weird things can happen.

If you just replaced the wiper motor, this should have been included with it. It may be that you got a bad one.

Comment: thanks,and it is on the back of the wiper motor,corect?

Comment: @cliffordparker - Yes. It's the black box which you connect the plug into which provides the power and direction for the motor.

Comment: Thanks im takeing the motor back and get another one,the pulse board came with it,THANKS